# why document.getElementById won´t work and I need to use document.forms instead?

Tags: javascript, forms, getelementbyid

I have this simple form, and I want to check out that the text input isn´t left empty.

So this is what I´ve done:

### This is the form:

```
<form onsubmit='return validar()' name="miForm" action="" method="POST">
<input id='tMonth' value='<?php echo $tMonth;?>' name='tmes' type='text'>  
...
```

### And here´s the validation code, inserted right after the  tag, and in between a  tag, of course:

```
function validar()
{
    mostrarValidacion=document.getElementById('mostrarValidacion');
    error=false;
    mensaje='';   
    var tMonth=document.getElementById('tmes');
if (!tMonth)  {
  mensaje += 'Debe completar todos los campos<br>';
  error=true;
  }
mostrarValidacion.innerHTML=mensaje; 
  if (error==true) {
      //con un return false nunca manda al servidor nada, no hace nada.
      return false;
  } else {
      return true;
  }  
}
</script>
```

Now that code isn´t working at all. It only worked when I replaced this line:

```
var tMonth=document.getElementById('tmes');
```

For this line:

```
var tMonth=document.forms["miForm"]["tmes"].value
```

**So why isn´t working with .getElementById?**

Comment: Clearly, the element you're targeting doesn't have that ID. It has the name. A name is not an ID. That's why they're different. When selecting by ID you need to give the ID not the name. And when selecting by name, you use the name, not the ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the ID 'tMonth'

```
<input id='tMonth' value='<?php echo $tMonth;?>' name='tmes' type='text'>
```

but you're trying to get it as tmes

```
var tMonth=document.getElementById('tmes');
```

change the above line to

```
var tMonth=document.getElementById('tMonth');
```